# How to implement Push Notification in react-native-ios

Tags: ios, push-notification, react-native

Please refer any step by step process for implementation of `Push Notification` in `react-native-ios`.

I have found this link:
[Push Notification- react-native](http://Push%20Notifications-%20react-native)

But I am unable to understand what would the perfect way to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Required for the register event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
 [RCTPushNotificationManager application:application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}


 // Required for the notification event.
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification
    {
     [RCTPushNotificationManager application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:notification];
    }
// Required to register for notifications
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings { [RCTPushNotificationManager didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings]; }
// Required for the register event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken { [RCTPushNotificationManager didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken]; }

// Required for the notification event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification
{
[RCTPushNotificationManager didReceiveRemoteNotification:notification];
}
```

Reference this link [How to Setup Push Notifications with React Native](http://bejopost.xyz/index.php?post=leeco-le-2-images-specs-feature-launched-must-know-le-2-le-2-pro-le-max-2-phone-price&id=TQmudJLhPx8&&s=How%2520to%2520Setup%2520Push%2520Notifications%2520with%2520React%2520Native)

[Setup Push Notifications with React Native tutorial](https://medium.com/@DannyvanderJagt/how-to-use-push-notifications-in-react-native-41e8b14aadae#.8oj8k1lzk)

Comment: @sandy: But you have not mentioned which part is mainly essential for push notification implementation.